# Can I programatically delete all entities in EDMX mode?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method to delete all my tables.

I'd like to know if I can:

(1) Iterate over the meta data in the model to accomplish the same thing?

(2) Reset the Identity Insert counts along the way?

Note: I don't want to delete the entire database, just all the tables.

Here's the code I want to convert to a generic loop:

```
    public void Delete() {
        using (var db = this.DirectAgentsEntities)
        {
            db.StartingBalances.DeleteObjects(db.StartingBalances);
            ...
            db.RecordSourceTypes.DeleteObjects(db.RecordSourceTypes);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
static class Extensions {
    static public void DeleteObjects<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class {
        foreach (var entity in data)
            set.DeleteObject(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be simpler to:

- drop the database
- recreate the database
- create the tables

The edmx file is just xml, so you could loop through it, then for each table you find:

- Delete from Tablename
- DBCC CHECKIDENT (Tablename, reseed, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Just write a stored procedure and import it to your edmx. That will be the fastest way with entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

I took the suggestion of Shiraz, and came up with a complete answer to my question as an imported SProc and a T4 template:

SProc:

```
ALTER procedure dbo.DeleteTable 
(
    @tableName varchar(500)
)
AS
    declare @sql varchar(1000)
    set @sql = 'delete from ' + @tableName
    exec (@sql)
    return
```

T4 Template:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml.Linq.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<# 
    string ns = "EomApp1.Formss.AB2.Model";
    string cn = "Util";
    string edmxFile = "\\ABModel.edmx";
    string inputContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile) + edmxFile);   
#>
namespace <#=ns#>
{
    static public class <#=cn#>
    {
<#DeleteTablesCodeGen(inputContent);#>
    }
}
<#+
    void DeleteTablesCodeGen(string input) 
    {
        XNamespace edmxNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx";
        XNamespace ssdlNS ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl";
        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xd = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(input);  
        var tables = 
                from c in xd.Root
                            .Element(edmxNS + "Runtime")
                            .Element(edmxNS + "StorageModels")
                            .Element(ssdlNS + "Schema")
                            .Element(ssdlNS + "EntityContainer")
                            .Elements(ssdlNS + "EntitySet")
                select new
                {
                    Name = c.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    EntitySet = c
                };
        foreach (var table in tables) 
        {
#>
        static public void Delete<#=table.Name#>(DirectAgentsEntities model) 
        { 
            model.DeleteTable("<#=table.Name#>");
        }
<#+
        }
    }
#>
```